# How to work with json in java?

Tags: java, json

I have a string  `String json = {  "result" : <status>started</status> }`

How I can get only the xml content?

I tried with `json.substring(15,json.lentgh-1 )` -> I succeed to get the xml content but I 
think should be better way to do it.

Do you know how I can do it in better way ?

**second issue**

How I can delete "/" from the content for example "/1" I want to change to  1

Comment: Use a json parser when working with jsons. Don't try to use string functions on it.

Comment: Do you have an example for json parser  what about the second issue ?

Comment: what is the second issue? And I guess if you just google *parse json in java*, you're going to get a lot of hits.

Comment: how i can change the content of "/1" to 1 to delete the " and the /

Comment: Where exactly is the "/1" in the example you provided? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but thinking that I am correct

Use the org.json library

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{ \"result\" : \"xml content in tag format\" }");
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(obj);
    JSONObject result= jsonObj.getJSONObject("result");
    System.out.println("result----->"+result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GSON or Jaxon. Its pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have valid JSON input, use a JSON parser library.
That way you can do reliable operations because the JSON will be parsed to a valid object (into a Map for example).

There are a load of JSON libraries for Java, for example [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

What you tried is only raw String manipulation.